# Error running when adding google services

Tags: android, android-studio

When adding the following lines to the gradle, at runtime the application does not start, only an error occurs and stops, this happens with android version 4.4 and less, from version 5 up does not occur this error.

```
multiDexEnabled true;

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

Could you help me please. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just clean your project and run the application again. For reference Check this link.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0):

Multidex support was added in API 21. So your devices are probably getting confused because of a command they don't understand. I would suspect that you should be able to see the runtime crash error in the logcat no?

Basically, you are going to have to find a work around for the lower API devices. One approach that people can take is to do the design in newer apis and only push the production version to older devices. The production should get rid of a lot of the function overhead that is compiled specifically for debug purposes.